# Print one number at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print each Fibonacci number at a time. How do I print the element every time I click on the button? Right now it runs into [object HTMLParagraphElement] error.

```js
 function calcFib(number) {
   if (number == 0)
     return 0;
   else if (number == 1)
     return 1;
   else
     return calcFib(number - 1) + calcFib(number - 2);
 }

 function showNumber() {
   var newEl = document.createElement("p");
   var node = document.createTextNode(calcFib(1));
   newEl.appendChild(node);



   document.write(newEl);
 }

 //  document.getElementById("print").onclick = showNumber();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="hello">Calculate Fibonacci's numbers</div>
  <button id="button" value="button" onclick="showNumber()">Calculate</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `calcFib(1)` will always return 1. So this would only keep adding 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
document.write(newEl);
```

to

```
document.body.appendChild(newEl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use

```
document.write()
```

Instead, add

```
<p id = "text"> </p>
```

and use this code below:

```
function print(msg) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += "<br> </br> " + msg;
}
```

The use:

```
print(calcFib(1));
```

in your function showNumber

```js
function calcFib(number) {
  if (number == 0) 
    return 0; 
  else if (number == 1) 
    return 1; 
  else 
    return calcFib(number - 1) + calcFib(number - 2); 
} 
function print(msg) {
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += "<br> </br> " + msg;
}
function showNumber() { 
  var newEl = document.createElement("p"); 
  var node = document.createTextNode(calcFib(1)); 
  newEl.appendChild(node);
  //document.write(newEl); 
  print(calcFib(1));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <div id="hello">Calculate Fibonacci's numbers</div>
      <button id="button" value="button" onclick="showNumber()">Calculate</button>
      <p id = "text"> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` replaces/overwrites the whole content of the page. Instead, you should use `parentElement.appendChild()`. And in this case, it's `document.body.appendChild()`

There is another problem. In your `showNumber` function, you use `calcFib(1)` which will return the same number every time you call it. You need to increment the number you pass into `calcFib` function, so you can get the rest of the sequence.

Examine the following code

```js
function calcFib(number) {
  if (number == 0)
    return 0;
  else if (number == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return calcFib(number - 1) + calcFib(number - 2);
}

var counter = 0;

function showNumber() {
  var newEl = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(calcFib(counter));
  newEl.appendChild(node);
  document.body.appendChild(newEl);
  counter++; // increments counter by 1
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">Calculate Fibonacci's numbers</div>
<button id="button" value="button" onclick="showNumber()">Calculate</button>
```